# My data doesnt prevails on my sql azure database, after login

Tags: sqlite, azure, mobile, uwp, azure-sql-database

I'm using Azure Mobile App SDK, and I have 4 tables Account, personal, Labor and Subscription.
I'll leave the code here of my models:

```
public class Account : TableData
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName ="userid")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "personalid")]
    public string PersonalId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "subscriptionid")]
    public string SubscriptionId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "subscriptionappleid")]
    public string SubscriptionAppleId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "subscriptiongoogleid")]
    public string SubscriptionGoogleId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "laborid")]
    public string LaborId { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return Equals<Account>(obj, this);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Id.GetHashCode();
    }
}

public class Personal : TableData
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "dadlastname")]
    public string DadLastName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "momlastname")]
    public string MomLastName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "sex")]
    public Gender Sex { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "birthdate")]
    public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return Equals<Personal>(obj, this);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Id.GetHashCode();
    }
}

public class Subscription : TableData
{
    [Required]
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "subscriptiontype")]
    public SubscriptionType SubscriptionType { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "subscriptiondate")]
    public DateTime? SubscriptionDate { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "expirationdate")]
    public DateTime? ExpirationDate { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "standardsubscriptiontype")]
    public SubscriptionType StandardSubscriptionType { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "standardsubscriptiondate")]
    public DateTime? StandardSubscriptionDate { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "standardexpirationdate")]
    public DateTime? StandardExpirationDate { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return Equals<Subscription>(obj, this);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Id.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

now as you can see Account model has Foreing Keys to Personal, Labor and Subscription.
whenever I make a change on Personal, labor or susbcription i updated my table and I can see at my cloud that the information has been changed, for example.

at Personal model I make a change on my birthdate from Oct 5th, 1981 to Oct. 6th 1981. and it updates successfully, but if I close my app and after 30 mins or 20 minutes I open the app again as soon as I login using the login method who has nothing to do with Sql Azure, the database information goes back to the previous values, and I have to wait like 20 or 30 minutes for this to happend I close my app and the reopen it inmediately the database or the record doesnt get affected.

Now this only happens with the table I mentioned before, If I make edition to other tables, they dont get affected by the situation I mentioned before.

Am I doing something wrong??? this didnt happened before, I have tried retiring offline support for this tables thinking that might be an issue with sqlLite but the issue still prevails.

I ignore the reason, of why is this happening.

Hopefully you can help me with some ideas, I dont have any clue about it.
Should I get rid of Foreing Keys???Should I delete the whole record and create a new one a reassign a new PersonalId or LaborId to the Account Model??? as a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstable I just solved it. I want to apologize because it was MY MISTAKE, it turns out that I hard coded my account data at the Configuration seeding method of  my cloud which run everytime someone login, the Azure Mobile Apps SDK has no flaws on it.

I had just deleted the data that rollback my information, or better said to updated my information.
It was a hard error to find because my code was fine, it was the behavior of my cloud that was wrong due to hardcoded the account information because I had an issue months ago, were i need to hardcode my account information in my cloud.

anyways I think this issue can be close now!!!